# Trying to select data between using columns in table - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have a problem where I am trying to select data between a specific IP range, everything is saved using `INET_ATOM`& `INET_NTOA`.

I keep getting an error back '#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row'

The subqueries causing the error are:

```
WHERE
    dst_address NOT BETWEEN(
    SELECT
        INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
    FROM
        accountingipranges
) AND(
    SELECT
        INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
    FROM
        accountingipranges
```

and

```
WHERE
     src_address NOT BETWEEN(
     SELECT
           INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
     FROM
           accountingipranges
    ) AND(
     SELECT
           INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
     FROM
         accountingipranges
```

My entire query is:

```
SELECT
    ip_address,
    SUM(upload_bytes) AS upload_bytes,
    SUM(download_bytes) AS download_bytes,
    SUM(upload_bytes + download_bytes) AS totalbytes,
    package_id,
    username,
    networkaccess,
    packagename,
    speedlimit,
    threshold,
    throttlelimit,
    extendeddata,
    datalimitamount,
    accountingdays
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT
            ipaccounting.src_address AS ip_address,
            SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) AS upload_bytes,
            0 AS download_bytes,
            users.username,
            users.networkaccess,
            users.extendeddata,
            datapackages.package_id,
            datapackages.packagename,
            datapackages.speedlimit,
            datapackages.threshold,
            datapackages.throttlelimit,
            datapackages.datalimitamount,
            datapackages.accountingdays
        FROM
            ipaccounting
        JOIN
            users
        ON
            users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.src_address
        JOIN
            datapackages
        ON
            datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
        WHERE
            dst_address NOT BETWEEN(
            SELECT
                INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
            FROM
                accountingipranges
        ) AND(
        SELECT
            INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
        FROM
            accountingipranges
    ) AND timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL datapackages.accountingdays DAY) 
AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    GROUP BY
        src_address)
    UNION ALL
        (
        SELECT
            ipaccounting.dst_address AS ip_address,
            0 AS upload_bytes,
            SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) AS download_bytes,
            users.username,
            users.networkaccess,
            users.extendeddata,
            datapackages.package_id,
            datapackages.packagename,
            datapackages.speedlimit,
            datapackages.threshold,
            datapackages.throttlelimit,
            datapackages.datalimitamount,
            datapackages.accountingdays
        FROM
            ipaccounting
        JOIN
            users
        ON
            users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.dst_address
        JOIN
            datapackages
        ON
            datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
        WHERE
            src_address NOT BETWEEN(
            SELECT
                INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
            FROM
                accountingipranges
        ) AND(
        SELECT
            INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
        FROM
            accountingipranges
    ) AND timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL datapackages.accountingdays DAY) 
AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    GROUP BY
        dst_address)
    ) a
GROUP BY
    ip_address
ORDER BY
    INET_ATON(ip_address)
```

My research states that I am missing 'IN' somewhere, I have tried putting it in different places but cannot get it right :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Between` is expecting a single result and the sub-query below returns more than one row. 
You need to add a `WHERE` clause to limit your results or change this query to use a join instead of a subquery.

```
SELECT
    INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
FROM
    accountingipranges
```

to

```
SELECT
    INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
FROM
    accountingipranges
WHERE %some condition to ensure only 1 row is returned%
```

or

```
SELECT
    INET_NTOA(iprangestart) AS iprangestart
FROM
    accountingipranges
LIMIT 1
```

or

I don't think you tables are set up this way, but here is a join example.

```
select *
from sometable A
INNER JOIN accountingipranges B on (%some condition%)
WHERE A.dst_address NOT BETWEEN B.iprange_start AND B.iprange_end
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Could you give me an example for the join query please?

Comment: Thanks bassxzero!! Please bear with me as I am still learning SQL... What I am trying to do is to not select data in the table that is inbetween two values for multiple rows of data, so basically my `accountingipranges` has the range start and range end, I have multiple rows that I want to exclude from my query. Is that doing it the correct way? I do not want to limit the query to one row else it will then leave out the rest of my data in the table.

Comment: @RaymondClaytonRudman I added `NOT` in front of `BETWEEN` in my join example. It sounds like you should be using the join method.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding correctly, is that suppose to be a subquery also? And what is `(%some condition%)` for? Sorry if I am being stupid...

Comment: @RaymondClaytonRudman `%some condition%` is a place holder for your join criteria. If you want to test against every row of the table you can just use `1=1`, which is a cartesian product.

Comment: Could you give me an example of where I should insert that into my entire query? I am getting errors when trying to insert it as a subquery?